# Remove whitespace from DataFrame/ csv

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to include 2 DataFrames into 1 csv.

My code runs and it prints the 2 DataFrames, however I wanna remove the blank space in columns D,E.F row 2, so that the information in line 3 appears right under its headers.

The DATA is correct and all, just formatting is my question here.

(This will make sense if you run the code, very small file)

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
line1=[]

url='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03548207'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div',id='main-content')
for item in content:
    title=item.find('h1',class_='tr-h1 ct-sans-serif tr-solo_record').text
    sponsor=item.find('div', class_='tr-info-text').text
    summary=item.find('div',class_='ct-body3 tr-indent2').text
    dict={'Title':title,'Sponsor':sponsor,'Summary':summary}
    line1.append(dict)

df=pd.DataFrame(line1)


url2='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03548207'
table1=pd.read_html(url2)[2]
dj=pd.DataFrame(table1)
kk=df.append(dj)
kk.to_csv('çode11.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Please make this a MRE. We shouldn't need to open links to see what is going on with your data

Comment: you dont need to open any link, the code saves into a csv.

Comment: But we still need to interact with the url, etc. Just show us the df. All the beautiful soup stuff has nothing to do with your question. Your question is I have x df and I want y df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` with `axis=1` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

line1=[]

url='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03548207'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div',id='main-content')
for item in content:
    title=item.find('h1',class_='tr-h1 ct-sans-serif tr-solo_record').text
    sponsor=item.find('div', class_='tr-info-text').text
    summary=item.find('div',class_='ct-body3 tr-indent2').text
    dict={'Title':title,'Sponsor':sponsor,'Summary':summary}
    line1.append(dict)

df=pd.DataFrame(line1)


url2='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03548207'
table1=pd.read_html(url2)[2]
dj=pd.DataFrame(table1)

kk = pd.concat([df, dj], axis=1)  # <--- pd.concat
print(kk)
kk.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                               Title  ...             Phase
0  A Study of JNJ-68284528, a Chimeric Antigen Re...  ...  Phase 1  Phase 2

[1 rows x 6 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does shift solve your problem?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[10, None, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'c':[20, None, 22, 23, 24, 25]})
df.loc[1:,'b':'c']=df.loc[1:,'b':'c'].shift(-1)
print(df)
```

Comment: it does not =-/